# Why does Adobe Camera Raw 6.4.1 offer different White Balance for different photos?

Tags: white-balance, jpeg, adobe-camera-raw

I am using Adobe Camera Raw v6.4.1 to view my Nikon d-90 photos on my computer and when I go to change the White Balance, for some photos I only get the choices:

```
As Shot
Auto
Custom
```

Yet for other photos, I get a much larger set of choices:

```
As Shot
Auto
Daylight
Cloudy
Shade
Tungsten
Fluorescent
Flash
Custom
```

Why do I see this variation and is there anyway to control it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any image that is not a native RAW format or DNG only provides the basic set of white balance options. This could be JPEG, as well as TIFF, PSD, or any other image format that Lightroom can load. The reason for this is that the full range of white balance and exposure adjustments are only really viable with RAW files to start with, and adjusting any one of the white balance or exposure settings too far will produce undesirable results with any RGB image.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you try to open a JPG image with Adobe Camera Raw or Adobe Photoshop Lightroom. Here is an example of what I see when I open a JPG image:

[image: JPG image options for white balance]